Fantasy manga about a guy whose fiancée leaves him for his younger brother. He gives a bullied girl a haircut
The main character is isekaied or reborn — I can't remember. He's born into a noble family and he's considered weak, but he's really physically strong and capable of using magic too. His fiancée leaves him for his younger brother.  I think in one chapter he fights an arena against his former fiancée.
There's a girl in his class that is getting bullied by other girls and they're threatening to cut her hair so he gives her a haircut and she's really cute.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  I haven't edited your content, because I'm not sure where the sentence breaks should be; could you [edit] it with some punctuation?
